# Word meaning "to make something erroneous"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What verb means "to make something erroneous or wrong"?
The context is

> However, in the first trial of the experiment, the yeast was siphoned through the device into the other test tube, _____ing the results.

Comment: You cannot *make* something erroneous/wrong: it either *is* erroneous/wrong, or it is correct. However, I understand what you mean from your example.  Possible words for use in your example are "voiding" or "nullifying" the results.  I'm sure there's a better expression, but it doesn't come to mind at the moment!

Comment: Normally (in informal terms) one would say "screwing up the results".  Otherwise, "invalidating" is probably the best choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**invalidate**

> :  to make invalid; especially :  to weaken or destroy the cogency of.
>   "factors that may invalidate the test results."

"Invalidate." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 12 Apr. 2016.

Answer (score 1):

The results have been *contaminated*.

> **Contaminate** *verb*
>   Make (something) impure by exposure to or addition of a poisonous or polluting substance
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contaminate)

This definition relates to the substance being literally contaminated by the contaminant, but the effect of the contaminant on the *results* can also be described with the same word. Here's an example:

> ... some outside astronomers said the group had underestimated the extent to which interstellar dust could have contaminated the results ...
>   [- Dennis Overbye](http://tech.mit.edu/V134/N41/cosmology.html)

Returning to your sample sentence, we have:

> However, in the first trial of the experiment, the yeast was siphoned through the device into the other test tube, *contaminating* the results.

Comment: I think you're giving the sentence a different meaning from what the OP intended.  The "results" of the experiment was not contaminated, but rather some physical component within the experiment.

Comment: @HotLicks The physical components were literally contaminated (per definition), but the effect on the *results* is also described with the same word, as the Overbye quote demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

If something was deliberately made wrong, with malicious intent, consider **sabotage**.

> any underhand interference with production, work, etc., in a plant, factory, etc., as by enemy agents during wartime or by employees during a trade dispute.

If it was perhaps not necessarily malicious, but interfered with in order to produce a deceptive result, then you might use **falsify**.

> 1.
>   to make false or incorrect, especially so as to deceive:
>   to falsify income-tax reports.
>   2.
>   to alter fraudulently.

Examples from Dictionary.com